# Ionic tabs & authentication - tabs are persisting after logout

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have an Ionic app which has tabs and authentication, the auth works perfectly but when logging out the tabs still display. Here is my login method:

```
  this.authProvider.loginUser(email, password).then(
    authData => {
      this.loading.dismiss().then(() => {
        this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
        //this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
      });
```

And here is my logout method:

```
  logOut(): void {
    this.authProvider.logoutUser().then(() => {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot('LoginPage');
      this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
    });
  }
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getRootNav` of `App` to remove the tabs from the view. Refer to [this working version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tab-issue).

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, App } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoggedInComponent } from '../../pages/loggedIn/loggedIn.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public app : App) {    
    this.loggedInPage=LoggedInComponent;
  }

  goTopage(){
    this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(this.loggedInPage);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I completely disagree with the advice in the answered post.
All suggestions involving `parent` and `getRootNav()` should be avoided. 
It is unmaintainable spaghetti. A much better idea is to subscribe to an Observable representing user authentication state in the app component and change the root page from there.

I'm not sure whether you're using the Ionic app with [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) or not. If you do using Firebase at the moment, here's a simple example code below that I strongly recommend you to use.

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor() {
  platform.ready().then((readySource) => {
      afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            console.log("App User", user);
            if (user) 
              this.rootPage = 'HomePage'; // Tabs reside here
            else 
              this.rootPage = 'LoginPage';
          });
          statusBar.styleDefault();
          splashScreen.hide();
        });
      }
```

`onAuthStateChanged()` method will monitor authentication state which takes in a callback. And this callback **fires off every single time the authentication state changes**. So whether a user logs in or a user logs out that will trigger user => {} this callback function.

**setting.ts** *Some page to place your sign out function.*

```
async logout() {
  const user: any = await this.authService.signOut();
}
```

Therefore, you don’t need to use `this.app.getRootNav().setRoot('Some Page');` anymore.  Firebase will take care of it everything for you.

I hope this post helps some others.